# Handle multiple urls with one (click)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I took over a project in pretty bad shape. I am struggling to figure out why the previous developer decided to code the social icon component like this. I am not sure how to handle the urls for each when clicked. Here is where I have the code now.

TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";
import {faFacebook, faTwitter, faLinkedin} from "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons";
import { FaIconComponent } from "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome";


@Component({
  selector: "app-social-media",
  templateUrl: "./social-media.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./social-media.component.scss"]
})
export class SocialMediaComponent implements OnInit {
  iconTwitter = faTwitter;
  iconFaceBook = faFacebook;
  iconLinkedIn = faLinkedin;
  public static SocialMediaClicked: EventEmitter<FaIconComponent> = new EventEmitter();
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  onIconClicked(ele:FaIconComponent){
    SocialMediaComponent.SocialMediaClicked.emit(ele);
    console.log(ele);

  }

}
```

HTML:

```
<fa-icon aria-label="Twitter" class="bopd-footer-icon"
  #twitter
  (click)="onIconClicked(twitter)"
  [icon]="iconTwitter"
></fa-icon>
<fa-icon aria-label="LinkedIn" class="bopd-footer-icon"
  #linkedIn
  (click)="onIconClicked(linkedIn)"
  [icon]="iconLinkedIn"
></fa-icon>
<fa-icon aria-label="Facebook" class="bopd-footer-icon"
  #faceBook
  (click)="onIconClicked(faceBook)"
  [icon]="iconFaceBook"
></fa-icon>
```

Comment: kind of depend what happens in the parent component receiving the event

Comment: what are you trying to do with the `emit`? are you trying to just redirect somewhere?

Comment: In app.component.ts I found this

```SocialMediaComponent.SocialMediaClicked.subscribe(ele => {
      console.log(ele.icon.iconName);
    }); ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

he is emitting informations about the social media including the name when the `icon` clicked, i think it should be deleted , cause it's usless, you can add a `switch-case` statement to handle the redirection directly :

```
constructor(private router: Router) { }    

onIconClicked(ele: any) {
            switch (ele) {
                case 'twitter':
                    this.router.navigate(['your_link_here']);
                    // or window.open(link, '_blank'); to open an external link in a new tab
                    break;
                case 'linkedIn':
                    this.router.navigate(['your_link_here']);
                    // or window.open(link, '_blank'); to open an external link in a new tab
                    break;
                case 'faceBook':
                    this.router.navigate(['your_link_here']);
                    // or window.open(link, '_blank'); to open an external link in a new tab
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: No, because of the binding he is actually emitting properties instead of strings, but those properties do not exist no the component so the event value will always be undefined

Comment: can i see a screenshot of the log of ele

Comment: I could test, but I don't think it is worth to mock up all of that stuff to prove a point, sorry

Comment: i'm pretty sure that he is emitting the name of the social media , to do the redirection later , and i think that it's usless , cause he can do it directly in the same method , see my updated answer

Comment: These social media links out to external site and should open in new tab.

Comment: you can do that using router navigate : `this.router.navigate([]).then(result => {  window.open(link, '_blank'); });` or directly without router : `window.open(link, '_blank'); `

Comment: @AymenTAGHLISSIA Can you show me how this should be in code. Maybe move into messaging so I can show you what is going on?

Comment: you can do it exactely like what i did in the answer

Comment: @AymenTAGHLISSIA This is not working

<code>onIconClicked(ele:any){
    SocialMediaComponent.SocialMediaClicked.emit(ele);
    console.log(ele);
    switch (ele) {
      case 'twitter':
        window.open('http://www.twitter.com', '_blank');
        break;
      case 'linkedIn':
        window.open('http://www.linkedin.com', '_blank');
        break;
      case 'faceBook':
        window.open('http://www.facebook.com', '_blank');
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
    

  }</code>

Comment: no , you should remove this line : `SocialMediaComponent.SocialMediaClicked.emit(ele);`

Comment: @AymenTAGHLISSIA I think removing that line just broke a bunch of things. I am no longer getting my console.log();

Comment: in the subscribe ?

Comment: no on the social-media.component.ts

  onIconClicked(ele:any){
    switch (ele) {
      case 'twitter':
        window.open('http://www.twitter.com', '_blank');
        break;
      case 'linkedIn':
        window.open('http://www.linkedin.com', '_blank');
        break;
      case 'faceBook':
        window.open('http://www.facebook.com', '_blank');
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
    

  }

Comment: @AymenTAGHLISSIA It was a dumb type mistake. Your solution worked well. I need to refresh my butt on these other methods with Angular